# What is better alternatives of bitmap for live video frame processing?

Tags: android, bitmap, face-detection, live-streaming

we have a ML model which take converted bitmap from frame and return the coordinates as a face detetction result. because this is a live video the frame which we are getting we are converting it to bitmap then we are sending this to our ML model that why it took lots of memory and low FPS.
my question is instead of converting frame to Bitmap what we can do better .

we tried to convert fame to bitmap but it give us low FPS, memory shortage so it didn't work well so i am expecting better solution instead of converting to bitmap.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on your data pipeline? How does frame data enter the device memory and what do you do with it afterwards? Because a bitmap might mean an actual memory region or an Android Bitmap object or something else yet.

Comment: actually we have an Android app and AI model . We starting the camera view for recording from front camera and from recording we are getting the frame then we convert this frame to bitmap and passing to AI model then Ai model giving ne the face detection coordinates. But because we are using bitmap it is given 4 frame / sec  FPS which is worst i want to find a way from which i will reach to 50 or 120 frame/ sec. that's why i want better solurion then bitmap. If there any another solution then please tell me. Thanks @Botje

Comment: The [Android tensorflowlite example](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/blob/master/lite/examples/object_detection/android_play_services/app/src/main/java/org/tensorflow/lite/examples/objectdetection/fragments/CameraFragment.kt) also uses bitmaps to grab images from the camera. If their approach *does* reach the required frame rate I would see what they do different from you. Notably they only allocate one bitmap and use it over and over instead of allocating a new one on every frame.

Comment: @Botje actually we tested and found that because we are passing bitmap in every millisecond it create low Frame Rate. Because we are doing it in every millisecond if it is only for one single image then it will work fine.